# How to localize admin portal in wso2am

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I've deployed apim-4.1.0 on my vm and got
`https://localhost:9443/carbon`.
I'm thinking of translating english to chinese, but there is a lot of work to do, I have to change many files. All the menus and pages to be changed. Is there any way to do this job faster? Please advise on the best way to localize.

Answer (score 0):

You should find these directions [1] helpful.

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/adding-internationalization/#adding-a-new-language

Comment: Sorry, that's carbon : https://localhost:9443/carbon, not devportal and publisher. What about carbon? That looks like wso2 is. How to add internationalization?

Comment: Apologies for missing your requirement about the management console specifically. I wish there was an easy answer for this but this is a more complex affair in Java since you have to take the source and modify it. 

This page should give you an idea of how to get started:
[Customizing the Management Console](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Customizing+the+Management+Console)